# Design of class Location in a World in a universe

Tags: c++, c++11, adventure-game

A `Plane` of existence is like a universe in the multiverse.  At first, I thought that a `Plane` will consist of many Worlds, and each `World` consists of many `Location`s.  But it is not so simple.

Here are some instances of `Plane`s:

- `MaterialPlane`: It has different `World`s, as I originally understood `Planes` to be.
- `Arcadia`: An `OuterPlane` (derived from `Plane`) that has 2 `Layer`s, which I suppose can be interpreted as Worlds, but has properties not found in Worlds.
- `Abyss`:  Similar to Arcadia, but has an infinite number of Layers.
- `TemporalPlane`: It has `TemporalWorld`s, where time has changed, but the physical location has not.  Not a very clear description, but that's what I found.
- `ShadowPlane`: No worlds, no layers, no subplanes, but has regions that continually flow onto other planes.  Not a very clear description, but that's what I found.
- `Neth`: A plane that has no substructure, and is a plane that is actually living.

This is the design I've come up with to set all this up.  Note that class `Location` has already been defined and used extensively in my program, as does the class `World`.

Originally, I only had `Location` that was attached to a `World`.  This is what I'm planning to expand this to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

enum PlaneEnum {MATERIAL_PLANE, SHADOW_PLANE, ABYSS, ARCADIA, NUM_PLANES};
enum RealmEnum {FORGOTTEN_REALMS, FAERUN, WATERDEEP, PAZUNIA, DRILLERS_HIVES,
    FORGOTTEN_LAND, GRAND_ABYSS, NUM_REALMS};

class Plane {} *MaterialPlane = new Plane, *ShadowPlane = new Plane;

class OuterPlane : public Plane {} *Abyss = new OuterPlane, *Arcadia = new OuterPlane;

const std::array<Plane*, NUM_PLANES> planes = {MaterialPlane, ShadowPlane, Abyss, Arcadia};

class Realm {
    private:
        const PlaneEnum planeEnum;
    protected:
        Realm (PlaneEnum p) : planeEnum(p) {}
    public:
        Plane* getPlane() const {return planes[planeEnum];}
};

class World : public Realm {
    public:
        World (PlaneEnum p) : Realm(p) {}
} *ForgottenRealms = new World(MATERIAL_PLANE), *Faerun = new World(MATERIAL_PLANE),
    *Waterdeep = new World(MATERIAL_PLANE);

class Layer : public Realm {
    public:
        Layer (PlaneEnum p) : Realm(p) {}
} *Pazunia = new Layer(ABYSS), *DrillersHives = new Layer(ABYSS),
    *ForgottenLand = new Layer(ABYSS), *GrandAbyss = new Layer(ABYSS);

class TemporalWorld : public Realm {};  // etc...

const std::array<Realm*, NUM_REALMS> realms = {ForgottenRealms, Faerun, Waterdeep,
    Pazunia, DrillersHives, ForgottenLand, GrandAbyss};

class Location {
    private:
        RealmEnum realmEnum;
    public:
        Location() = default;
        Location (RealmEnum r) : realmEnum(r) {}
        Realm* getRealm() const {return realms[realmEnum];}
        Plane* getPlane() const {return getRealm()->getPlane();}
        // One of the many reasons for using RealmEnum as data member instead of Realm*.
        void save (std::ostream& os) {os << realmEnum << '\n';}
        void load (std::istream& is) {
            int n;  is >> n;  realmEnum = static_cast<RealmEnum>(n);
        }
};

int main() {
    Location* myLocation = new Location(GRAND_ABYSS);
    if (myLocation->getRealm() == GrandAbyss) std::cout << "Correct.\n";  // Correct.
    if (myLocation->getPlane() == Abyss) std::cout << "Correct.\n";  // Correct.
    std::ofstream saveGame("save.txt");
    myLocation->save(saveGame);
    saveGame.close();

    std::cout << "\nGame ended.  Loading saved game...\n";
    std::ifstream loadGame("save.txt");
    Location* locationNewGame = new Location;
    locationNewGame->load(loadGame);
    if (locationNewGame->getRealm() == GrandAbyss) std::cout << "Correct.\n";  // Correct.
    if (locationNewGame->getPlane() == Abyss) std::cout << "Correct.\n";  // Correct.
}
```

I already have a template class `Portal<T>` that allows travelling to a different `World` (by letting `T = World`).

Now I can let:

- `T = Layer` to travel to a different `Plane`, or
- `T = Plane` to travel to a `Plane` that has no subregions, or
- `T = TemporalWorld` to travel to the `TemporalPlan`e, etc...

Comment: It's not clear to me what one would actually do with this.  Can you add some context as to its use?

Comment: I'm just trying to design how the cosmos is set up in this adventure game.  I already have a class `Portal<T>` that allows travelling to a different `World` (by letting T = World).  Now I can let T = Layer to travel to a different Plane, or T = Plane to travel to a Plane that has no subregions, or T = TemporalWorld to travel to the Temoral Plane, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're suffering from an excess of mimesis here. You've done an impressive job of translating your fantasy setting from English prose into a C++ object model... but sadly that's not worth anything, because the *computer* will never appreciate it, and the *player* will never see it.

Let's start over, as if we were designing an adventure game program, instead of transcribing a worldbuilding session. We probably have a player (just one player, so we can just use a singleton named `player` to hold his data), and the player has a current location, right?

```
enum Location : int {
    FORGOTTEN_REALMS, FAERUN, WATERDEEP, PAZUNIA, DRILLERS_HIVES,
    FORGOTTEN_LAND, GRAND_ABYSS,  // ...
};

struct Player {
    Location location;
    // ...other stuff, like inventory and so on...
} player;

void newGame() {
    player.location = GRAND_ABYSS;
}

void travel(Location newloc) {
    player.location = newloc;
    describe_surroundings();
}
```

Okay, so now we have all the mechanics that we need in order to put the player in a location and to move the player from one location to another.

But what about *planes*? How will we represent that certain locations belong to a given *plane*? Ah, well, that sounds like a table lookup.

```
enum Plane : int {
    MATERIAL_PLANE, SHADOW_PLANE, ABYSS, ARCADIA, // ...
};

struct LocationData {
    Plane plane;
    std::string description;
    // ...
};

std::map<Location, LocationData> locData = {
    { FORGOTTEN_REALMS, { MATERIAL_PLANE, "You wander in the Forgotten Realms." } },
    { FAERUN, { MATERIAL_PLANE, "You are welcomed in Faerun." } },
    { WATERDEEP, { MATERIAL_PLANE, "You explore Waterdeep." } },
    { PAZUNIA, { ABYSS, "You climb among the crags of Pazunia." } },
    { DRILLERS_HIVES, { ABYSS, "You skulk among the Drillers' Hives." } },
    { FORGOTTEN_LAND, { ABYSS, "You search the Forgotten Land." } },
    { GRAND_ABYSS, { ABYSS, "You fall swiftly through the Grand Abyss." } },
};
```

Now we can express things such as

```
newGame();
assert(player.location == GRAND_ABYSS);
assert(locData[player.location].plane == ABYSS);
player.location = FAERUN;  // travel to a new location
assert(locData[player.location].plane == MATERIAL_PLANE);
```

and even

```
void travel(Location newloc) {
    if (locData[player.location].plane != locData[newloc].plane) {
        puts("You have no means of travel between the planes.");
    } else {
        player.location = newloc;
        describe_surroundings();
    }
}
```

None of this stuff requires a complicated object model; we're not trying to mirror a whole fantasy world in our adventure game program. Instead, we're trying to mirror just enough of it to manage the player's *experience* of being in that world. Any concept that doesn't directly affect the player's experience can be tossed out of the program.

And in case you're wondering, `describe_surroundings()` would be implemented something like

```
void describe_surroundings() {
    puts(locData[player.location].description);
}
```

Don't overcomplicate things. :)